# Use signal function to create Profile object upon creation of User object

Tags: django, django-signals

I am a following a tutorial on Django and have the following models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default = 'default.jpg', upload_to = 'profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username} Profile"
```

I use the `register` view to create a `User` object:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # if form was submitted w data
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST) #instantiate form w post data
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() #save user to db
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username') #get this to print out success message
            messages.success(request, f"Your account has been created. You are now able to log in.") #Formatted string literal for f-string
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form':form})
```

Upon creation of a `User` object I am trying to use signals to create a `Profile` object. I have created a `signals.py` file in my app directory:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

#Run this function every time a User is created
@receiver(post_save, sender = User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created: #if User was created
        Profile.objects.create(user = instance)

 @receiver(post_save, sender = User)
 def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     instance.profile.save()
```

and have imported the signals within the `ready` method of `apps.py`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    # To make signals work you have to import your signals
    # inside the ready method of our apps.py module
    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

However, upon the creation of a new `User` there is still no associated `Profile` object. Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: how are you creating the User object?

Comment: @amulya349 Sorry, did not realize this was relevant. Just added the code for my `register` view underneath the code for models.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`UsersConfig.ready()` never runs** and thus your signals are not *seen* by Django

**Solutions**

1. Add `users.apps.UsersConfig` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`

OR

2. Add `default_app_config = 'users.apps.UsersConfig'` in your `__init__.py`

OR

3. Just add your signals directly in your models.py

Checkout: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information, I guess you have not defined `default_app_config` in the `__init__.py` file of the app.

Open the `__init__.py` which would be an empty file. 
In that, add a line which specifies the value of `default_app_config` which equals to the path of `UsersConfig` class which you have defined in apps.py.

It should be following:

`default_app_config = 'users.apps.UsersConfig'`

Add this line and it should work.